# Accessing ext4.vhdx via another machine?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, vhd

Is there anyway to mount or access the ext4.vhdx on another machine? I understand that accessing the linux environment files while WSL is running will likely corrupt them; but I want to be able to access this hard disk image when WSL is inactive?

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean remotely? If so I can't help, but I had a WSL2 installation on a computer/disk that refused to boot and simply transfering the `ext4.vhdx` from that and drop it over the file from a fresh WSL2 distribution made my complete old installation come to life.